# Cx Oracle 'TNS could not resolve the connect identifier'

Tags: python, linux, oracle, ldap

I am connecting to an Oracle DB using LDAP and the Python cx_Oracle library. I have proper sqlnet.ora, ldap.ora and tnsnames.ora files. On my Windows machine everything works fine using the 12.1 Oracle client and the following Python code:

```
import cx_Oracle
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user/password@db, mode=cx_Oracle.SYSDBA)
```

I have installed the Oracle instant client 12.1 on my Linux machine (Debian) following the zip file installation method advised on the Oracle website (at the bottom of https://www.oracle.com/be/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html).
ldconfig correctly lists the oracle client libraries and their paths.

I copy the exact same sqlnet.ora, ldap.ora and tnsnames.ora files from my Windows machine to my Linux machine
in /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1/network/admin, as advised by the cx_Oracle documentation.

Now running the above Python code on my Linux machine I have the following error:

`cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`

I tried as well setting the environment variable `TNS_ADMIN=/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1/network/admin` and `ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1/` with no success neither

Could any of you help me debugging this and understand why the client config on my Linux machine does not work?

Comment: Never set ORACLE_HOME with Instant Client.  No need to set TNS_ADMIN, because you already moved the files to the default location.  Your error is elsewhere: whatever hostname you have in the config files couldn't be reached.

Comment: I am able to ping the hosts in the config files with success. Is there any way to make the cx_Oracle library print out the config that has been loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed the latest 19 client and everything works as expected.

Comment: What do you mean by "latest 19 client"? Can you elaborate ?